# squid disallow emailing

Tags: squid

I'm running a squid proxy server and one of my clients used the ip for spamming. My question is... how do I set squid to block emailing?

Comment: Are you sure squid is implicated in the spamming ?

Comment: Suggest you post your squid.conf here, or if it is large a link to it on a pastebin style site. Also have you checked whether you have a misconfigured MTA on the squid server?

Answer (score 1):

Squid doesn't email.  Squid proxies HTTP/FTP traffic.  If your squid acl (see @Andy Smith) permits IP addresses that aren't under your control to use your proxy, you need to lock that down, an open proxy is commonly used by spammers to access webmail sites to send spam.

Take a look at:
http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid24s1/access_controls.php

If you are trying to prevent your (legitimate) clients from accessing web mail sites, you can add something like

```
acl webmail dstdomain hotmail.com mail.yahoo.com gmail.com mail.google.com live.com  #(add domains you want to block)   
http_access deny webmail      
http_access allow all
```

Answer (score 0):

Squid shouldn't by default allow proxying of everything - the default configuration is rather tied down.

What are your ACLs like? The output of `grep "^acl" /etc/squid/squid.conf` (with anything sensitive taken out, obviously) would be useful.